# When would be the case when we can only use Riemann-Stieltjes integral or Lebesgue integral instead of Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

As title says, can anyone present:

1) an example when it is more appropriate to use Riemann-Stieltjes integral instead of Riemann integral

2) an example when we can only use Lebesgue integral instead of Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: Do you mean examples of a function that is Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable?

Comment: The Riemann integral is a sepcial case of riemann stieltjes, you should explain a bit more what you mean with the rieman stieltjes integral exists but not the riemann integral

Comment: Maybe.. this clarifies...?

Comment: i mean that you should say that riemann stieltjes integrabel for any integrating function or just for a special one

Answer (score 1):

The dirichlet function should be a nice example for 2)
It is defined as 
$$D(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rl}
1 & x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
0 & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
As $\mathbb{Q}$ is a nullset, the integral is $0$.